# How to show that a Behavior is an ownedBehavior of an active class in UML?

Tags: uml

As detailed in pag. 191 of the [UML 2.5 Specifications](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/PDF), `Class` generalises `BehavioredClassifier` which, as detailed at pag 169, allows to specify the classifier behaviour through the property `classifierBehavior`.

As stated at pag 193 of the same specs:

> An active object is an object that, as a direct consequence of its
>   creation, commences to execute its classifierBehavior, and does not
>   cease until either the complete Behavior is executed or the object is
>   terminated by some external object.

I would like to know if there is any way to show the connection between the Class and the Behavior associated to the property  `classifierBehavior` in any of the available UML diagrams.

The best way to do this that I have come up with is the following:

[image]

which unfortunately does not meet the UML 2.5 spec.

If there is not any graphical way to show this connection, the only way to elicit this connection is through associated explanation in natural language.

Comment: Which version are you referring? There is not `BehavioredClass`. Only `BehavioredClassifier`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My misspelling error. Edited and corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not graphical representation of behavior which is defined as classifierBehavior. If you use some of case tool, good tool should support features to you to defined, that one of owned behaviors of classifier is also classifier behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is basically no need to show what you want.

[image]

A Class realizes (together with other classes) a Use Case. The latter includes Activities which may be traced to individual classes. You may add this trace, but the superordinate realization is usually more than sufficient information. Basically this is what the UML spec says (p. 638) by

> The behaviors of a UseCase can be described by a set of Behaviors (through its ownedBehavior relationship), such as Interactions, Activities, and StateMachines, as well as by pre-conditions, post-conditions and natural language text where appropriate. It may also be described indirectly through a Collaboration that uses the UseCase and its Actors as the Classifiers that type its parts. Which of these techniques to use depends on the nature of the UseCase behavior as well as on the intended reader. These descriptions can be combined...

However, if you have the need to explicitly point out the relation you can do this with the stereotyped dependency as you did.

**Addendum** I leave my previous answers here, though they were made with wrong assumptions about the real center of the question:

You can only show the lifetime of objects in a SD like this:

[image]

The first message is a `New` operation. The X at the end of the lifeline shows the object termination.

If you the object has just "a life on its own" you can show that with an initial self-message:

[image]

Messages and actions are different renderings of the same thing (a class operation):

[image]

Since an `Activity` is a defined sequence of `Actions` you can use a single SD to represent an `Activity` by showing the involved `Actions` as messages.

Comment: What I am after is way to depict the connection between the class and its classifierBehaviour. For example, let's say that the calssifierBehaviour of Class1 is Activity1. I would like to be able to depict this relationship in some UML diagram.

Comment: See explanation on last example.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edited question, for a clarification on what I am after.